# ag-grid not showing nested json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, ag-grid

I have problem with ag-grid. I tried to bind my data with ag-grid. So when I enter new grade in my system I expand ag-grid by one column :

```
var newGrade = {headerName: "Grade", field: 'grades[' + indexOfNewGrade + '].value'};
this.$scope.columnDefs.push(newGrade);
this.$scope.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(this.$scope.columnDefs);
this.$scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData(this.selectedEventLog.getEntries());
```

I am 100% sure that for example : `this.selectedEventLog.getEntries()[0].grades[0].value` returns 1 when I am not seeing this value in ag-grid. On the other hand when I write `'grades['+indexOfNewGrade']'` it works fine but it binds to whole object not 'value' property.
Grade object:

```
export class Grade {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you inputing it as a string? I can't seem to grasp what you're doing. What I would simply do is `field: grades[indexOfGrade].value.toString()`. Note the lack of `'`, since you actually want to get the value of that particular `Grade` stored at `indexOfGrade` inside the array `grades`. Afterwards you get the `value` property, and **only then** you make it a string.

***Update***

I think I got what you're trying to do. Are you trying to use [value getter expressions](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-value-getters/index.php)?

If that's so, your code should be something like this:

```
{
    headerName: "Grade", 
    field: 'newGrade' + indexOfNewGrade.toString(),
    valueGetter: 'data[' + indexOfNewGrade.toString() + '].value'
}
```

Comment: nop, it's because it has to be evaluated later by ag-grid, it has to be a string

Comment: @Walfrat updated, I think I got it right this time :)

Comment: well i prefered the function approach because i didn't test if ag-grid evaluate array indexing, but i guess it migh work, if so both our answers are the same i guess :P

Comment: @Walfrat They're almost the same. You're using a value getter (function), and I'm using a value getter expression (which leaves ag-grid to do the evaluation). I only approached the problem like this because OP was trying to construct an expression in his question. But I'd use your solution in my projects, I don't really like string evaluation (eval is evil, you know....)

Comment: ag-grid don't use eval function it has his own way of doing this.

Comment: @Walfrat I know. But since I can't go around researching all the libraries out there, I rather not use it at all :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the evaluation support the array evaluation.

Instead you should use a value getter :

```
function buildValueGetter(index){
     return function(params){
        return params.data.grades[index].value;
     }
}

var newGrade = {headerName: "Grade", id: 'grades-'+indexOfNewGrade, 
    valueGetter:buildValueGetter(indexOfNewGrade)};
```

Relevant documentation about valueGetter : https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-value-getters/index.php